# Setting the address of Deserializer

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, serial, clock, deserialiser

I have this [MAX9278](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX9278-MAX9282.pdf) GMSL1 Deserializer.

I have 3 below questions:

1. How to configure the CX/TP pin if I want to use the coax mode?
2. And how to arrive at the address of the deserializer if I connect both ADD0 and ADD1 as ground? I am not able to understand the table 10.
3. I have 800 * 480 TFT 3.1 inch.

[image]

I have arrived at the below PCLK calculation :

Vertical Resolution   =  800    Pixels

Horizontal Resolution = 480 Pixels

Frames Per Second   = 60fps

Blanking Percentage = 20%

Approximate PCLK    = (800 * 480 * 60 * 120%) / 1000000 = 27.648MHz

Is the above calculation for PCLK correct? What would be a good value to set for my above TFT?
And there is no provision to connect external crystal to the deserializer?

Comment: How does 800x480xfps make any sense? Frames per second ought to refer to the frequency in which the whole screen is updated, regardless of resolution. Otherwise it would be "pixels per second" or some such.

Comment: Sorry, Could you please correct my calculation?

Comment: No, I haven't got a clue how this part works.

Comment: The deserializer part or the TFT?

Comment: I meant the Maxim IC.

Comment: Yes, I find it difficult. Could you only help me with the addressing? My question number 2

Comment: No, sorry. I don't have the time or the will to read a 75 pages long datasheet.

Answer (score 0):

1. Look at datasheet table 10. to determint how to select coax pin with CX/TP.
2. Look at datasheet table 1. to determine address when address pins are grounded.
3. PCLK should be sent from the transmitting end. PCLK should be within TFT datasheet limits. We don't know the parameters of the display, nor the transmitting end, so any guess is good. It is best to stick with exact standard formats instead of rough calculations.

Comment: Yes I looked at table 10 and table 1. So, for coax mode, I will set the CX/TP pin to high by pulling it up. And for the address, ADD0 and ADD1 are connected to the ground. So, my deserializer address would be 90 (hex) ?